# How to open new page and send data when click on a tag in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, href

I have datatable with 3 icons in a column

### js

```
var datatableVariable = $('#projects-progress').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: [
    { 'data': 'project_name' },
    {
       mRender: function (o) { return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View </a>'; }
  },
] )};
```

I want when the user click on view, to open details page of the selected row. So, I think I need to pass some data somewhere and open new page of the details. How can I do this? Thanks

### edit

I try this

```
{
  'data': 'project_number',
  "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
   return '<a href="project_details.aspx?id="+data class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View </a > <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>';
                                  }
                                },
```

### The solution

```
'<a href="project_details.aspx?id=' + data + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View </a > <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>';
```

It was a syntax error.

Comment: You can pass data using query string in href.

Comment: @AnkitBhanderi How to do this?

Comment: u can pass data like in href="URL?VARIABLENAME=VARIABLEVALUE".

Comment: @AnkitBhanderi take a look on my edit

Comment: data is belong to which type example:(string,object etc)?

Comment: @AnkitBhanderi integer

Comment: u can find the answer in below answer section.

Comment: @AnkitBhanderi and how to deal with 'data' value in project_details page?

Comment: U can get query string value in project_details page like below.
Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()

Comment: @Ankit Bhanderi do you mean write it in page load? project_details.aspx.cs?

Comment: yes of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `meta.row` from `render` function to get current `row ID` and then pass it to a `function`. After that, get the row data using `table.row(number).data()` and pass that data in query string. Something like this:

```
//declare a variable to store reference to datatable object
var table;

table = $("selector").DataTable({
  //... your other configuration here

  columns: [
    {
        "render": function(row, type, data, meta) {
            return '<i class="fa fa-pencil" onclick="navigate(' + meta.row + ')"></i>';
        }
    }
  ]
});

//this function is outside the datatables initialization block
function navigate(rowId) {
  //get row data here using row id
  var rowData = table.row(rowId).data();

  //for example we want to redirect to details page with user name and age
  window.location.href = "project_details.aspx?name=rowData.username";
}
```

**or** you can use `anchor button` directly like this:

```
columns: [
    {
        "render": function(row, type, data, meta) {
            return '<a href="project_details.aspx?id=' + meta.row + '"></a>';
        }
    }
  ]
```

- **`meta.row`** will give you **datatable's internal row id (zero based)**
- **`data`** will give you **your data object.** You can use this get whatever property you need, like `id`

Comment: and how to deal with 'data' value in project_details page?

Answer (score 0):

> your solution is here...

```
'<a href="project_details.aspx?id=' + data + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View </a > <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>';
```

Comment: `data` represents data object. You can not append it as `string` in `query string`. See [columns.render's documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

Comment: @Syed Ali Taqi: Please refer the comments I discussed with alaa.

Comment: yes it done. my mistake in the syntax. I wrote: 'a href="project_details.aspx?id="+data'

Comment: @Ankit: his required `data` to pas as query string is `integer` but the `render's function data` is an `object`.